# Can't get collision or trigger to work with 2 2D objects

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I have 2 sprites, both with "Box Collider 2D" component attached. I put the same detection functions in scripts attached to both objects:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
    Debug.Log ("Something triggered with me!!!");
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D( Collision2D coll ) { 
    Debug.Log ("Something collided with me!!!");
}
```

- This is Unity 5.2.1f1
- I've tried both trigger checked and trigger unchecked. I would prefer to use trigger because I don't need the objects to physically affect each other.
- I've verified the spelling of the function names and parameters. I've also tried removing both parameters.
- There is NO 2D rigid body on either object (I don't need one, do I?)
- Movement is currently being handled by a Translate() in the Update() loop of the objects.
- I've verified using "Edit Collider" that there is a decent box around each.
- I've RTFM'ed and read through most of the issues everyone else has seen here but I can't see what I am missing. 
  I've placed all collidable objects on the same layer called "Character" and it appears in the 2D collision matrix in the project settings and is checked.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add a RigidBody2D to any object you want to be physics-enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i am not mistaken you should add a rigidbody2d.

Just try it. And write a short line of code which resets the other collider (the object that is moving towards your player object / testing object).

I am not at home to test it for you but this is my guess ;)

Comment: Indeed, at least one of the objects needs a rigidbody attached for collision. In this case, a Rigidbody2D.

Comment: I call that "ghosting". gameObjects without rigidbodies are ghosts to me :p

Comment: Confirmed. Adding a RigidBody2D to one of the two objects made it all work. I can't explain why, unfortunately, since neither object really requires physics and it begs the question "what's the Box Collider 2D for?" but it works now.

Comment: I think it's nonsense but just remember. Use atleast 1 rigidbody (prefarable the player object should contain one).

I am no unity specialist so i can't tell you :)